# PHP insert into MySQL and record position number

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Goal: Record the position order of each form item on insert.

I'm allowing the user to dynamically add and delete form fields(that functionality is working with JS).  For simplicity sake, the user designs their form to look like this:

**Form:**

Subtitle

Paragraph

Subtitle

Image

My database would contain a table for each field:

[image]

I wrote a simple function to get the index number from an associatative array, I'm guessing I can record that in each table in a column called "position"?

```
function arrayValuePosition($value, $array)
{
    return array_search($value, array_keys($array));
}

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    echo  arrayValuePosition($key, $array);
};
```

What is the best way to record this position number and also loop through inserting into the various tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could be more simple to use a single table:

```
Table: form_data
Fields:
id - INT - PRI auto_increment
fields_enabled - ENUM - possible values: 'subtitle', 'paragraph', 'image'
subtitle
paragraph
image
```

You can store the records as normal rows in this table, and the information regarding the form fields the user has enabled can be stored in the field fields_enabled.

It would also be easy to browse the existing records.

Comment: Thank you, I have been racking my brain trying to figure this out and here you give me such a simple way to do it.  thank you!  I'm not sure why you added "subtitle paragraph image" as other fields?  Wouldn't it just make more sense to combine those into a field "text"

Comment: You're welcome. Regarding combining multiple fields in a single text field, you will lose the advantage of being able to run searches on those records (WHERE conditions). Also sorting the records by any of those fields would be difficult. Not to mention that if you really want to combine them in a single field, you would have to use a separator which is also hard to define in order not to conflict with existing chars in the field values. I see only advantages in using separate fields.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply.  No I understand the advantages etc.  Wouldn't the "fields_enabled" distinguish what data was entered in the potential "text" field.  Then I can do my searches etc just calling out a specific "fields_enabled".  Then I can remove "subtitle, paragraph, etc"  Yes/No?

Comment: The fields_enabled will allow you to know what fields the user has selected; it can be useful for example to display to a user a form only with the fields he had selected. You said in your original description: "I'm allowing the user to dynamically add and delete form fields". fields_enabled holds this info.